# Nested loop statement incorrect results

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a piece of a program that will ask for a student name and 10 of his/her classes. The code is suppose to prevent duplicate entries but every time I run the program it says everything is each entry already exist. I have gone through this thing a thousand times and cannot figure it out for the life of me. Any insight on my problem would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
   string name;
   string classes[10];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  string test_name;
  student entry;

  cout << "Enter the name of the student you wish to insert (string) \n"; 
  cin >> entry.name;

  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter class number " << i + 1 << " For " << entry.name << endl; 
    cin >> test_name;

    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
      if(test_name == entry.classes[j])
      {
         cout << "Class already exists for " << entry.name << ". Please try again.\n";
         i -= 1;
      }
      else
      {
          entry.classes[i] = test_name;
      }
  }
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a nested `if` statement.

Comment: sorry should say loop not if

Comment: I believe this will only loop 9 times, not 10: `for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)`. So make it `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` instead. Won't fix your issue but you'll fail your assignment otherwise!

Comment: no it definitly will run 10 times. 0-9 is ten not 9 total numbers

Comment: The loop only runs for 0-8.  The condition `i < 9` is tested before each loop iteration, and as soon as that condition is false, the loop ends.  It never gets a chance to run while `i` is nine.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `for` loop tests all 10 positions, including the position you're inserting the new class into.

You really want to scan only the populated positions, see if there is any match, and then, *outside the loop*, add the new class if it's not a duplicate.

Pseudo-code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    get class 'i';

    bool repeat = false; 

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)  // Only check previous classes (j < i)
        if (test_name == entry.classes[j])
        {
            repeat = true;
            break;
        }

    if (repeat) 
    {
         output the error
         rewind 'i'
         continue;
    } else
    {
         insert the new entry
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep.  This is the problem.

Comment: even if the array is unpopulated why would it think that one of the empty slots is equal to the entry?

Comment: @user2837034: In the original loop, the program was inserting the new entry in slot `i` on every iteration it _didn't_ find a match between `test_name` and `entry_classes[j]`.  The result was that by the time `j == i`, the program had set `entry_classes[i]` to `test_name`, so the loop would detect a redundant entry on the iteration where `j == i`.  The fact that the `j` loop also tested the entries for `j > i` was a separate, _additional_ bug.

Comment: @user2837034 :  Did I explain the situation clearly enough?  If not, let me know, and I can try to unpack it further.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is in Java you can do something similar, and I think it meets the requirements of disregarding any input that is already in the classes array and adding it if its not until the 10 classes are reached :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ArrayList < String > classes = new ArrayList < String > ();


        System.out.println("Enter the name of the student you wish to insert (string) \n");



        while (classes.size() < 10) {


            BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
            String s = bufferRead.readLine();


            for (String classy: classes) {
                if (classy.equals(s)) {
                    System.out.println("This is duplicate class");
                    break;

                }


            }
            classes.add(s);



        }
        System.out.println("Ten Classes have been input");



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To really see, what's wrong add this line before your `if()` statement:

```
cerr << "test_name == \"" << test_name << "\", entry.classes[j] == \"" << entry.classes[j] << "\"\n"
```

I expect, what you see, is that test_name is empty for some reason, and I know that all the uninitialized strings will show up as empty strings. But, no matter what is wrong, the line above should show it.